# Find example where: h ◦ f = f ◦ k, but: h ≠ k for a two element Set

Tags: category-theory

How do you prove that the following statement is incorrect:

> If $h \circ f = f \circ k$, then $h = k$

When using the following guides:

- Use a set with two elements
- With three endomaps for $f$, $h$, and $k$
- Where $f$ is invertible

---

I can prove the statement false (without the guides above) with the following scenario:

- $A = \{x, y, z\}$
- $f$ is a constant map to $x$
- $h$ maps $x$ to $x$, and the others to $z$
- $k$ is a constant map to $z$

In this scenario:

- $h \circ f$ is a constant map $x$
- $f \circ k$ is also a constant map $x$
- but $h ≠ k$

However the book I am following (Conceptual Mathematics: A First Introduction to Categories) specifically asks for a two element set with three endomaps.

Thanks for you help!

Comment: What is the composition $f\circ g$? Are these maps?

Comment: Yes, maps. Sorry if that wasn't evident in the question. I'm not sure how best to word things yet. I'm following a book about Category theory, this exercise is from a chapter on Isomorphisms.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $A=\{1,2\}$, $f(1)=2,f(2)=1$, $h(1)=h(2)=1$ and $k(1)=k(2)=2$. Then $h\circ f=h$ and $f\circ k=h$ but $h\not=k$.

Answer (score 2):

How about this?
$$A=\{0,1\}$$
and $h(x)=0$, $k(x)=1$ and $f(x)=1-x$, $\forall x\in A$. Your idea of taking constant functions was good, you were close...